# Using Pyglet how could someone apply multiple view like translations to multiple groups?

Tags: python, pyglet

I understand the question doesn't say much, so I'll just try to explain my problem.

I'm working on a project in Pyglet that is a 2D top down game with Labels representing tiles on a grid (The reasoning for Labels is to emulate ASCII graphics, and that its easier then making art by hand). I already have all my batches and groups set up and even a camera, and what I'm looking for is an optimization over some of my code.

I figured that instead of having mass amounts of sprites off screen that represent the whole map, I could instead reuse pre-existing sprites to make the game run faster, to do this I split up my tiles into groups that would be children of the main group that held them originally.

Basically, I have one `MapGroup` instance (the parent group), which holds 36 `MapGrid` instances (the children groups) and each `MapGrid` holds 1024 `RenderTile` instances (the tiles).

What I initially did was that whenever a new `MapGrid` would be needed, say the camera moved to the right to where some empty space would be, `MapGroup` would look at every grid furthest in the opposite direction and set those `MapGrid`'s internal coordinate values to cover that empty space, making it seem like a new grid appeared, but its just a reused grid that was offscreen.

The main issue then came with the actual `RenderTile`s, and is what I'm mostly trying to work around, my best way to move them so far has been to iterate through each `RenderTile` in every `MapGrid` that moved and setting there position that way. Its better then rendering a whole new `MapGrid` and I even scheduled each movement with a 1 ms delay from the last making it not lag much to at all, but its still not great, and I feel like there should be better.

My main attempt to optimize was by trying to apply the same translate that `MapGroup` has onto each `MapGrid`, but for some reason, the `set_state` only seems to run on the first `MapGrid` made, so from there I tried to make the `MapGrid` `set_state` iterate through each `MapGrid` and use values from the iteration instead, but that too didn't work. I even tried making it so that `MapGroup`, isn't a pyglet group, instead only something that manages groups, but that also had the issue where `MapGrid` still only ran the first instance made. If there is a way to separate out these `set_state` calls so that it does actually set and unset for each induvial `MapGrid`, that would be great, otherwise I don't have a clue where to take this.

Here is code that I'm working with extra comments on what does what:

```
from pyglet.text import Label
from pyglet.graphics import Group
from pyglet.clock import schedule_once
from pyglet.math import clamp,Vec2,Vec3
from pyglet.gl import glEnable,glDisable,glScissor
from random import randint

class RenderTile(Label): # Main Tile
    def __init__(self,internalCoords,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.internalCoords = internalCoords

        self.x = internalCoords[0] * 16 + self.group.gridCoord[0] * 512
        self.y = internalCoords[1] * 16 + self.group.gridCoord[1] * 512
        #Initial values, fine on its own, but idealy the self.group.gridCoord[0] * 512 can be removed as set_state would handle the relative position


    def rePos(self,dt,newPos): #Simply called by MapGrid's update
        self.position = newPos



class MapGrid(Group): # Child Group
    def __init__(self,gridCoord,win,batchPass,order=0,parent=None):
        super().__init__(order,parent)
        self.gridCoord = gridCoord
        self._window = win
        # pyglet window, passed from parent

        self.internalTiles = {} 
        # Dict that holds each Tile, their keys are their coordinates in the grid

        gridTestColor = (randint(0,255),randint(0,255),randint(0,255),255) 
        # Random color for whole grid, mostly for distinction

        internalXSet = 0
        while internalXSet < 32:
            internalYSet = 0
            while internalYSet < 1:
                self.internalTiles[(internalXSet,internalYSet)] = RenderTile(internalCoords=(internalXSet,internalYSet),text="##",font_name="dayton",font_size=8,color=gridTestColor,batch=batchPass,group=self)
                internalYSet += 1
            internalXSet += 1
        # While loops that add each RenderTile to the grid, currently makes the grid 32x1 for testing purposes, it will be 32x32 by the end

        self.testInternalGrid = RenderTile(internalCoords=(16,16),text=str(self.gridCoord),font_name="dayton",font_size=24,color=(255,255,255,255),batch=batchPass,group=self,anchor_x="center",anchor_y="center")
        # Debug item, simply shows the grids position at its center

    def update(self):
        eventIterations = 0
        for tile in self.internalTiles:
            schedule_once(self.internalTiles[tile].rePos,eventIterations,(tile[0] * 16 + self.gridCoord[0] * 512,tile[1] * 16 + self.gridCoord[1] * 512,0))
            eventIterations += 0.001
        self.testInternalGrid.position = (256 + self.gridCoord[0] * 512,256 + self.gridCoord[1] * 512,0)
        self.testInternalGrid.text = str(self.gridCoord)
        # Updates the grids position, this is the unideal solution that I want to replace


    # def set_state(self):
    #     for grid in self.parent.internalGrids:
    #         self.parent.internalGrids[grid]._window.view = self.parent.internalGrids[grid]._window.view.translate(Vec3(-grid[0]*10, -grid[1]*10, 0))
    #         print(grid)

    # def unset_state(self):
    #     for grid in self.parent.internalGrids:
    #         self.parent.internalGrids[grid]._window.view = self.parent.internalGrids[grid]._window.view.translate(Vec3(grid[0]*10, grid[1]*10, 0))

    # This set_state was what I was messing with, if there is some way to make this work as intended that would be absolutley amazing



class MapGroup(Group):
    def __init__(self,win,map,batchPass,x=-1040,y=-540,z=1.0,order=0,parent=None):
        super().__init__(order,parent)
        self._window = win
        # pyglet window

        self.mapData = map
        # currently unused, will hold the data for the map, like what a tile should look like and what not

        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self._z = z
        # Probaly should have just called this zoom instead of z, but it doesn't break anything yet, so its fine

        self.internalGrids = {}
        # Dict that holds each Grid, their keys are their coordinates in the map

        self.memoryPos = 0

        internalXSet = -3
        while internalXSet < 3:
            internalYSet = -3
            while internalYSet < 3:
                self.internalGrids[(internalXSet,internalYSet)] = MapGrid((internalXSet,internalYSet),win,batchPass,parent=self)
                internalYSet += 1
            internalXSet += 1
        # While loops that add each MapGrid to the MapGroup


    @property
    def position(self):
        return Vec2(self.x,self.y)

    @position.setter
    def position(self,new_pos):
        self.x,self.y = new_pos
        self.update()

    @property
    def z(self):
        return self._z

    @z.setter
    def z(self,new_z):
        self._z = clamp(round(new_z,1),0.5,2)

    def update(self):
        # All the following is frankly a pain to explain, but this is the code that looks for the furthest opposite grid and tells it to move
        XGridOffset = (self.position[0]+1040)/128-self.memoryPos*2
        XGridCheck = abs(XGridOffset)
        self.memoryPos += int(XGridOffset)
        while 1 <= XGridCheck:
            xCheckList = [grid[0] for grid in self.internalGrids]
            xMin = min(xCheckList)
            xMax = max(xCheckList)
            if 0 < XGridOffset:
                xChangeList = [grid for grid in self.internalGrids if self.internalGrids[grid].gridCoord[0] == xMin]
                for grid in xChangeList:
                    shiftingGrid = self.internalGrids.pop(grid,None)
                    newCoord = (xMax+1,shiftingGrid.gridCoord[1])
                    shiftingGrid.gridCoord = newCoord
                    self.internalGrids[newCoord] = shiftingGrid
                    shiftingGrid.update()
            elif 0 > XGridOffset:
                xChangeList = [grid for grid in self.internalGrids if self.internalGrids[grid].gridCoord[0] == xMax]
                for grid in xChangeList:
                    shiftingGrid = self.internalGrids.pop(grid,None)
                    newCoord = (xMin-1,shiftingGrid.gridCoord[1])
                    shiftingGrid.gridCoord = newCoord
                    self.internalGrids[newCoord] = shiftingGrid
                    shiftingGrid.update()
            else:
                xChangeList = [grid for grid in self.internalGrids if self.internalGrids[grid].gridCoord[0] == xMin]
                for grid in xChangeList:
                    shiftingGrid = self.internalGrids.pop(grid,None)
                    newCoord = (xMax+1,shiftingGrid.gridCoord[1])
                    shiftingGrid.gridCoord = newCoord
                    self.internalGrids[newCoord] = shiftingGrid
                    shiftingGrid.update()
            XGridCheck -= 1

    # Main set_state
    def set_state(self):
        glScissor(400, 0, 1280, 1080)
        # Basically the space the map takes up, assuming a 1920x1080 display
        glEnable(3089) #GL_SCISSOR_TEST = 3089
        # Didn't feel like importing from pyglet.gl.gl, so I just put its number in instead

        map_matrix = self._window.view.translate(Vec3(-self.x, -self.y, 0))
        map_matrix = map_matrix.scale(Vec3(self.z, self.z, 1))

        self._window.view = map_matrix

    def unset_state(self):
        glDisable(3089) #GL_SCISSOR_TEST = 3089

        map_matrix = self._window.view.scale(Vec3(1/self.z, 1/self.z, 1))
        map_matrix = map_matrix.translate(Vec3(self.x, self.y, 0))

        self._window.view = map_matrix
```

Outside of rendering, here is what is minimally required to get the code working:

```
import pyglet
from render import MapGroup,MapGrid,RenderTile
# render.py is the name of the file holding the other code

config = Config(double_buffer=True)
display = pyglet.canvas.get_display()
screens = display.get_screens()

window = pyglet.window.Window(1920,1080,fullscreen=True,vsync=True,screen=screens[2])
# Change screen as needed, its just what I have it set to

main_batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
map_group = MapGroup(window,{},main_batch)
# Main batch and group

fps_display = pyglet.window.FPSDisplay(window=window,color=(0,255,0,255))

#gui_group = pyglet.graphics.Group(order=2)
#holdThingTest = pyglet.shapes.Rectangle(0,0,400,1080,color=(75,75,75,255),batch=main_batch,group=gui_group)
#holdThingTest2 = pyglet.shapes.Rectangle(1680,0,240,1080,color=(75,75,75,255),batch=main_batch,group=gui_group)
#Bad naming I know, but its just simple boxes to help show where the map should be, uncomment if wanted

@window.event
def on_mouse_drag(x,y,dx,dy,buttons,modifiers):
    if buttons & pyglet.window.mouse.MIDDLE:
        map_group.position = (map_group.x - dx,map_group.y - dy)
# Event for camera movement, just hold and drag middle mouse

@window.event
def on_mouse_scroll(x,y,scroll_x,scroll_y):
    map_group.z += scroll_y/10
# Event for zooming, just scroll your mouse wheel

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()

    main_batch.draw()
    fps_display.draw()
# Event for drawing, kind of a well duh

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pyglet.app.run(1/60)
# Thing that runs the code, not much else to say
```

I understand that I should only show what's necessary, and its a slight pain to craw through someone else's 170 some odd lines of code, but as far as I know, anything could be the issue, so I rather it be available in case I simply overlooked a one line change that fixes everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more messing around, I found out that by simply setting each `MapGrid` to have a unique order fixed it, so the fixed change was simply this:

```
        orderSet = 0
        internalXSet = -3
        while internalXSet < 3:
            internalYSet = -3
            while internalYSet < 3:
                self.internalGrids[(internalXSet,internalYSet)] = MapGrid((internalXSet,internalYSet),win,batchPass,order=orderSet,parent=self)
                orderSet += 1
                internalYSet += 1
            internalXSet += 1
```

The only thing I would want to note is that the order needs to be unique for each `MapGrid`, setting them all to 1, or 2 they seem to cause the same error again.